# Sirato Explorer

Tags: private-blockchain, explorers, besu

I am able to setup a private ethereum network using hyperledger besu in my localhost:8545. I want to view the blocks that has been added to the blockchain, any guides on how can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how I can view the datas that has been added to the blockchain, not by contract interaction but by only opening a file or a UI, like a xampp database, and by that I can see the blocks that has been added, or not the blocks just the data with timestamp or whatsoever

Comment: Did you follow their page guide https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/private-networks/how-to/monitor/sirato-explorer/?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sirato Explorer, the quickest way to get up and running is with docker compose. You need to run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/web3labs/sirato-free.git
cd docker-compose
docker-compose pull
NODE_ENDPOINT=http://<node_endpoint> docker-compose up
```

The explorer runs on port 80 by default, if you want to use a custom port e.g 26000, set the PORT environment variable and the explorer will be accessible via http://localhost:26000.

```
NODE_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8585 PORT=26000 docker-compose up -d
```

For further information you can head to the [docs](https://github.com/web3labs/sirato-free/blob/master/docker-compose/README.md).